# What is meaning of $ \exists x \exists y [ T(x,y) \land \neg \exists u \exists v (T(u,v) \land ( u \neq x \lor v \neq y))] $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$ \exists x \exists y [ T(x,y) \land \neg \exists u \exists v (T(u,v) \land ( u \neq x \lor v \neq y))] $

where  T (x,y) means $x$ is teacher of $y$.

Now first part says that $ \exists x \exists y  T(x,y) $ means there exists at least one teacher having at least one student. For understanding lets have $(t_1, (P,R)) (t_2, (S,R)) (t_1, (P,R,S))$ where $t_i$ are teachers and $P,R,S$ are students.

Second part says there does not exists any (teacher student) pair in which either teacher is from set {$t_i$} or student is from set (P,R,S). So answer becomes there are atleast one teacher having more than one students.

i am not sure of this. Thank you

Comment: Second part: try moving inside the negation sign...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $ \exists x \exists y [ T(x,y)  \land \forall u \forall v (T (u,v)  \rightarrow (u=x and v=y)) ]$

Comment: Exactly.........

Comment: So it means that there exists atleast one teacher having atleast one student and every other T,S pair is equal to one of them

Comment: i.e. There is exactly one teacher-student pair

Comment: Exactly: it expresses a uniqueness condition.

Comment: But why does it have to be one teacher student pair ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what is uniqueness condition ?

Comment: @BenjaminWang why it can't be that there are 3 teacher student pairs and every other pair is one of them ?

Comment: Usually, in maths, to prove that an object $p$ satisfying certain conditions is unique, it goes like this: assume there is an object $q$ that satisfies these conditions; then, we arrive at $q = p$; it follows that $p$ is the unique such object. This makes sense intuitively, because suppose your name is Jessica and others call you Jess, and we prove that Jessica = Jess. Then, all this is really saying is that there is only one Jessica after all (just with different names).

Comment: @BenjaminWang By this definition it means that there is exactly one teacher student pair. But then $\exists $ is read as at least not exactly one

Comment: If you only had $\exists x \exists y T(x,y)$, then of course this means "there is at least one TS pair". However, as we showed, the full statement (as written in your question and your comment earlier) shows that this TS pair is in fact the only (unique) one.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Okey Thank you